# Trouble with saving arrayList in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save an `ArrayList` in `SharedPreferences` but I get errors which is

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>
> > com.example.host.myapplication.adapter.DataModel
> >     Here my code samples.

**DataModel.java**

```
public class DataModel extends ArrayList<String> {

    public String name;
    public boolean checked;

    public DataModel(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

**PickCategoryActivity**

```
//...
 adapter = new CustomCategoryAdapter(getArrayList("CATEGORY"), getApplicationContext());
//... 
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<DataModel> list, String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply(); 
}

public ArrayList<DataModel> getArrayList(String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DataModel>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

**CustomCategoryAdapter.java**

```
private ArrayList dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    public CustomCategoryAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_pick_category_row_list, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public DataModel getItem(int position) {
        return (DataModel) dataSet.get(position); // i get an error here
    }
//...
```

Error logcat:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.example.host.myapplication.adapter.DataModel
>           at com.example.host.myapplication.adapter.CustomCategoryAdapter.getItem(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:45)
>           at com.example.host.myapplication.adapter.CustomCategoryAdapter.getView(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:69)

Comment: Why are you extending `ArrayList` in `DataModel`? I think its unnecessary.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the data modeling why are you extending `ArrayList`? Is this really necessary?

Comment: When i don't extend ArrayList in DataModel i get another error in getArrayList() method ---- Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asakirullah.myapplication/com.example.asakirullah.myapplication.activity.PickCategoryActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

Comment: error is in your data parsing then. No need extend Arraylist

Comment: I removed ArrayList extend and also  removed DataModel in Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DataModel>>() {}.getType(); and result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to save an `ArrayList` in `SharedPreferences` but I get
>   errors which is
>
> > java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
> >
> > > com.example.host.myapplication.adapter.DataModel Here my code samples.

That's because you're trying to convert DataModel to ArrayList.

You need to change the DataModel to simple pojo like this:

```
public class DataModel {

    public String name;
    public boolean checked;

    public DataModel(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

No need to extends ArrayList because your model is for a single data item.

Then you need to modify your saveArrayList and getArrayList methods to more readable methods like `saveCategories` and `getCategories()` on the following:

```
private static final CATEGORIES_KEY = "CATEGORIES";
public void saveCategories(List<DataModel> list){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(CATEGORIES_KEY, json);
    editor.apply(); 
}

public List<DataModel> getCategories(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());

    List<Model> models;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(CATEGORIES_KEY, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataModel>>() {}.getType();

   try {
     models = gson.fromJson(json, type);
   } catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException exception) {
     // You need to catch the error here
     Log.d("CONVERT", exception);
   }

   return models;
}
```

You can see that the **key** is changed as a constant and moved inside the methods. This is because we need to hide the details to the method caller. Adapter should not know the details.

Then you can use get the category list with:

```
adapter = new CustomCategoryAdapter(getCategories(), getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `CustomCategoryAdapter`

You have declared your `dataSet` as `ArrayList` but in your `CustomCategoryAdapter` constructor argument is `ArrayList<DataModel>`

**Use this**

```
ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet
```

**Instead of this**

```
private ArrayList dataSet;
```

Comment: @KaiTera have u change this in your `CustomCategoryAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()); 
String json = new Gson().toJson(yourlist);
prefs .edit().putString("testArray",json).commit();
```

try commit(); which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously